# Cloud Functions works but logs not appearing

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I just added Cloud Functions to an older project that I have had for a a couple of yrs now. I get a Deployment complete! message and I get the responsea inside the Log console but the *Hello World* `console.log` statements do not appear. In the same file I added my own functions which successfully work but `console.log` statements are printed there. The odd thing is inside one of my newer projects the console.log statements from the same code below successfully prints.

I checked the google upkeep and everything is working fine on their end.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  console.log("Hello Again!!!");
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably because it is a function, and runs on some server, not on your browser. You want to see the `console.log` on your browser right?

Comment: i want to see in the console, it usually appears. I think this must be a Firebase issue because I just tried it on a different project that it was working fine on and now it's no longer working.

Comment: Cloud Functions interface has changed the past years. Not sure that has impacted the logs aggregation, but it's possible. Redeploy your function, without code update to update it.

Answer (score 2):

To update to the latest version in terminal run: `$ sudo npm install -g firebase-tools`

I reached out to the Firebase team and this was their response:

> I've read your description in detail and it seems like the issue is
> caused by some ingestion delay for some regions in Cloud Logging which
> is handled by GCP (for more details please check the [GCP
> Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com)).
>
> However, a similar problem was previously reported in a [Github
> issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/821), and apparently it was only happening with old versions of
> the Firebase CLI tools, so my recommendation is to update this command
> line interface to the [latest version](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases/tag/v9.6.1) (v9.6.1) and redeploy the
> functions once again , this will allow to validate if the function is
> storing the logs correctly. Also you can try to update the npm
> libraries used in order to keep everything in the latest versions.

You can check your version of firebase in terminal: `$ firebase --version`

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions interface has changed the past years.

Not sure that has impacted the logs aggregation, but it's possible.

Redeploy your function, without code update to update it